# How to bind datasource in kendo schedular multiselect

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

Trying to connect multiselect in kendo schedular's custom view, but it didnt display data source data. data coming from server & stored inside resources. Other fields displayed ok. Is somebody can help to me with this?

Data Source

```
$scope.attendeesDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read:
            {
                url: "odata/AttendeesOData",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: function(data) {
                return data["value"];
            },
            total: function(data) {
                return data["odata.count"];
            },
            model: {
                fields: {
                    value: { from: "Id", type: "number" },
                    text: { from: "text", type: "string" },
                    color: { from: "color", type: "string" }
                }
            }
        },
        serverPaging: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        pageSize: 15
    });
```

Scheduler Initialization

```
    $("#ksheduler").kendoScheduler({
        date: new Date(),
        startTime: new Date("2015/1/1 07:00 AM"),
        dateHeaderTemplate: kendo.template("<strong>#=kendo.toString(date, 'd/M')#</strong>"),
        height: 600,
        views: [
            "day",
            { type: "workWeek", selected: true },
            "week",
            "month",
            "agenda",
            { type: "timeline", eventHeight: 50 }
        ],
        timezone: "Etc/UTC",
        editable: {
            template: kendo.template($("#schedulerTemplate").html())
        },
        dataSource: {
            type: "odata-v4",
            batch: false,
            sync: function (e) {
                var scheduler = $("#ksheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
                if (scheduler) {
                    scheduler.refresh();
                    scheduler.dataSource.read();
                }
            },
            transport: {
                //cache: false,
                read: {
                    url: "odata/ScheduleOData",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                },
                update: {
                    url: "odata/ScheduleOData",
                    type: "Post",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: function (response) {
                        if (response.Attendees == null) {
                            response.Attendees = [];
                        }
                        if (response.Clients == null) {
                            response.Clients = [];
                        }
                        if (response.Tutees == null) {
                            response.Tutees = [];
                        }
                        if (response.Placements == null) {
                            response.Placements = [];
                        }
                        return response;
                    },
                },
                create: {
                    url: "odata/ScheduleOData",
                    type: "Post",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: function (response) {
                        if (response.Attendees == null) {
                            response.Attendees = [];
                        }
                        if (response.Clients == null) {
                            response.Clients = [];
                        }
                        if (response.Tutees == null) {
                            response.Tutees = [];
                        }
                        if (response.Placements == null) {
                            response.Placements = [];
                        }
                        return response;
                    },
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: function (data) {
                        return "odata/ScheduleOData(" + data.Id + ")";
                    },
                    type: "Delete",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                },
                parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                    if (operation == "destroy") {
                        return;// kendo.stringify(data);
                    }
                    var d = kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap(data, operation);
                    delete d.$inlinecount; // <-- remove inlinecount parameter    
                    delete d.$callback;
                    return d;
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: function (data) {
                    return data["value"];
                },
                total: function (data) {
                    return data['@odata.count'];
                },
                model: {
                    id: "taskId",
                    fields: {
                        taskId: { from: "Id", type: "number" },
                        title: { from: "Title", defaultValue: "Interview", validation: { required: true } },
                        start: { type: "date", from: "StartDate" },
                        end: { type: "date", from: "EndDate" },
                        startTimezone: { from: "StartTimezone" },
                        endTimezone: { from: "EndTimezone" },
                        description: { from: "Description" },
                        recurrenceId: { from: "RecurrenceID", defaultValue: 0 },
                        recurrenceRule: { from: "RecurrenceRule" },
                        recurrenceException: { from: "RecurrenceException" },
                        isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" },
                        isInterview: { type: "boolean", from: "IsInterview", title: "Interview", defaultValue: true },
                        isSession: { type: "boolean", from: "IsSession", title: "Session" },
                        attendees: { from: "Attendees", nullable: true },
                        clients: { from: "Clients", nullable: true },
                        tutees: { from: "Tutees", nullable: true },
                        placements: { from: "Placements", nullable: true },
                        ownerId: { from: "OwnerID", defaultValue: 0 },
                        location: { from: "Location" },
                        notes: { from: "Notes" },
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        resources: [
            {
                field: "attendees",
                dataSource: $scope.attendeesDS,
                multiple: true,
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "id",
                title: "Tutors",
                nullable: true
            }
        ]
    });
```

Multiselect inside custom template

```
<div class="k-edit-label">
    <label for="Attendees">Tutors</label>
</div>
<div data-container-for="Attendees" class="k-edit-field">
    <select id="Attendees" multiple="multiple" name="Attendees"
            data-role="multiselect"
            data-bind="value: attendees"
            data-source="attendees"
            data-text-field="text"
            data-value-field="id"
            data-value-primitive="true"></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all the way you select the datasource, hmm i dont think it's correct, use this way instead :

You need to add edit events where you can add the datasource to the editable template on the scheduler.

```
edit: function(e) {
            debugger;
            var ownerId = e.container.find("#ownerId").data("kendoDropDownList");
            var attendeesId = e.container.find("#attendeesId").data("kendoMultiSelect");
            //bind the widget to the resouces
            ownerId.dataSource.data(e.sender.resources[0].dataSource.data());
            attendeesId.dataSource.data(e.sender.resources[1].dataSource.data());
          }
```

I have modified [kendo dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/IVeVE/3) sample of scheduler where when you edit the event of the scheduler it will use an custom editable template and add a multiselect

I also modify kendo example and add multiselect to its custom template,

```
<div data-container-for="attendeesId" class="k-edit-field">
            <select id="attendeesId" data-bind="value:attendeesId" data-role="multiselect" data-value-field="id" data-text-field="name"/>
    </div>
```

And modify the resources data

```
resources: [
            {
              field: "ownerId",
              title: "Owner",
              dataSource: [
                { text: "Alex", value: 1, color: "#f8a398" },
                { text: "Bob", value: 2, color: "#51a0ed" },
                { text: "Charlie", value: 3, color: "#56ca85" }
              ]
            },{ 
              field: "attendeesId",
              title: "Attendees",
              dataSource:[
                            {name:"Brown",id:"1"},
                            {name:"Daniel",id:"2"},
                            {name:"John",id:"3"},
                            {name:"Hawk",id:"4"},
                            {name:"Borne",id:"6"},
                            {name:"Deryl",id:"7"},
                            {name:"Jack",id:"8"}
                            ]
            }

          ],
```

Edit : regarding your comment "I dont see in your example where defined attendeesId in model & how I can get already selected attendees."

Assuming you want to store the multiselect which datatype is array of object,
i have read that currently kendo model cant handle complex datatype like object or array according to [kendo forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/dealing-with-data-which-includes-a-field-having-an-array-of-objects), so the workaround on this refering to this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ja8MK/12/). You can store it on separate `kendo observable` and bind the observable object to your multiselect on edit function added this `kendo.bind(e.container.find("#attendeesId"), viewModel);`. And also take a look at the parameter map where i retrieve the selectedAttendees then add it into option.model then continue the process to Save/Update to the server

```
if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
    if(typeof options.models !== "undefined"){
      options.models[0].selectedAttendees = viewModel.selectedAttendees;
      console.log("the models here :",options.models);
    }
    return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
}
```

I also have modify my example on this new [kendo dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ImEQo), where you can see that the console log of the options.models now have selectedAttendees attribute.

Comment: Good day, When I'm tryed to implement your example I have an error inside edit method:  Error 1476 The property 'resources' does not exist on value of type 'kendo.ui.Scheduler'. Also another question: I dont see in your example where defined attendeesId in model & how I can get already selected attendees.

Comment: Assuming you want to save the selected attendees that is array, currently kendo model does not support array dataype but there is a workaround to this please see my updated answer